# Laravel Redis key format not working as expected

Tags: laravel, redis

I am storing set as:

`Redis::sadd("user:{$user->id}:series:{$series->id}", $lesson->id);`

and expecting the keys to be as: `user:1:series:1` but Redis is storing keys as: `laravel_database_user:1:series:1`

```
user:1:series:1                    <=== Expected key format
laravel_database_user:1:series:1   <=== Actually getting this format
```

Difference is between `user` and `laravel_database_user`. I am wondering why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

In database.php file, laravel stores keys with prefix as:

`'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),`

therefore I am getting this result